# I need to rank offices of different sizes on survey response percentage

Tags: survey, normalization, ranking

I have 100 offices. Some with 1-person and another with 700-people.
We've sent them a survey and I want to order them by response %.
With that in mind, the office of 1-person who has responded, yielding a response rate of 100% should not be ranked ahead of a 700-person office who has a response rate of 85%.

How would I accomplish this mathematically?

```
Pasca   26  31  84%
Manvel  12  14  86%
Howell  84  97  87%
Dublin  133 149 89%
Phoenix 8   9   89%
Cleve   18  19  95%
Richm   3   3   100%
Bama    1   1   100%
Anch    1   1   100%
```

Comment: If response rate is not your criterion, what is? The question has the form "I want to rank my observations on a scale I am not specifying, so how do I that?" How do you expect us to reply? The only other simple criteria that seem possible are size of office and number of responders.

Comment: "I want to order them by response %". In my example, I would subjectively think that Dublin be ranked 1st since they have they have a combination of the most people and highest %.

Comment: That doesn't give you a rule. It's like saying that that you want to use a sloping line on a scatter plot. What's the slope to be?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to calculate, say, the lower bound of a binomial proportion confidence interval and order by that. [There are many ways to do this, of varying complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). You would want to pick a method that takes the possibility of low sample sizes into account - the Normal approximation will not behave well.

A more expedient method is to weight the samples towards a fixed point, like `0.5`. You can do this easily by adding constants to the numerator and denominator. Adding 1 to the numerator and 2 to the denominator will nudge all the proportions toward 0.5. Adding 100 to the numerator and 200 to the denominator will have a much stronger effect. You can tune this however you would like. As cited in Wikipedia link above, the adding 1 and 2 implementation is suggested in Agresti & Coull 1998, *"Approximate is better than 'exact' for interval estimation of binomial proportions"*. (They frame it as adding single constant, 1, to the number of successes and the number of failures.)

On your example, adding 1 and 2 knocks the 1/1 groups down to 67%:

```
                       adding 1 and 2
8    Bama   1   1 100% 0.6666667 0.6000000
9    Anch   1   1 100% 0.6666667 0.6000000
7   Richm   3   3 100% 0.8000000 0.7142857
2  Manvel  12  14  86% 0.8125000 0.7777778
1   Pasca  26  31  84% 0.8181818 0.8000000
5 Phoenix   8   9  89% 0.8181818 0.7692308
3  Howell  84  97  87% 0.8585859 0.8514851
4  Dublin 133 149  89% 0.8874172 0.8823529
6   Cleve  18  19  95% 0.9047619 0.8695652
```

But if you think Dublin should be the highest, you'll need to go higher. Adding 2 and 4 does it

```
                                 adding 2 and 4
8    Bama   1   1 100% 0.6666667 0.6000000
9    Anch   1   1 100% 0.6666667 0.6000000
7   Richm   3   3 100% 0.8000000 0.7142857
5 Phoenix   8   9  89% 0.8181818 0.7692308
2  Manvel  12  14  86% 0.8125000 0.7777778
1   Pasca  26  31  84% 0.8181818 0.8000000
3  Howell  84  97  87% 0.8585859 0.8514851
6   Cleve  18  19  95% 0.9047619 0.8695652
4  Dublin 133 149  89% 0.8874172 0.8823529
```

Comment: The rigour is somewhat diminished by the need not only to choose a method but also to decide on the confidence levels. That bites most with the smallest samples.

Comment: I've done it this way before as well. Another approach that does not depend on choosing a lower bound is to use empirical shrinkage and sort by the shrunk percent, [here is an example](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/) for percentages.

Comment: @NickCox as you are pointing out in comments to the original post, OP doesn't have a clear criterion in mind. In such cases the most practical approach is often to play around with a simple technique until something "looks right". There's no pretense of rigor.

Comment: I tend to agree, so why use the word "rigorous" at all?